# "Bad number of vertex" when converting a model made in Blender

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, conversion

I would like to preface this by saying that I only use Blender for one specific activity: I make football football player face models for a football video game (something tells me you may have a had a couple of people like 'round these parts before ;) ), so my knowledge of modelling is quite limited.

Each time I make a new football player's face, I take a .bin file from the game in question that contains the model and texture of a given player, I paint over the texture with a photo of the player whose face I want to make in Photoshop, then use a tool called FEI 2010 to convert the .bin file into a .fef file. and open it with my Blender 2.49

Normally, when I'm done modelling, I overwrite the .fef file and then convert it back to a .bin file, which is then ready to be used in the game, but for some reason, when I try to convert the finished player face model as contained in the .fef file back to a .bin file, I get an error message in FEI saying  "Bad number of vertex. You should NOT delete any vertex". Now, I've had this error a couple of times before back when I was just starting to use FEI/Blender - whenever I tried to write over a .bin file different than the one I used to generate the .fef file, but I've since learned my lesson.

I can't think of anything I may have done differently this time around, which leads me to think I must've clicked something without being aware of it and deleted some part of the model in Blender (in all honesty, I had to look up what a "vertex" even was before asking this question)? Does anybody have any idea how to go around this, please? I still have the .fef file which I can import back into Blender and edit freely... I just can't re-convert the .fef. back to a .bin, which makes the model useless, and it takes quite a bit of work to make each of those faces.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Given the quite ancient Blender version and add-on, you might have a trouble finding someone to answer this. Perhaps you could link to the specific version of add-on you're using? This was others may at least have a chance to reproduce this on their own system.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. The version I use is indeed ancient, but it has served me well  and the learning curve was steep enough to keep me from upgrading. I am of course more than happy to provide any all additional information, but this sort of goes back to my previous comment about my having a limited knowledge of the nomenclature, etc. By "add on", do you mean the "FEI 2010" software I mentioned? If so, the version is 2.0 b. Irrespective of the version, does Blender offer the possibility of importing another model and replacing the one currently worked on? Thank you.